# LateInitializationError: Field '_userData@32329253' has not been initialized

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Getting this when trying to initialize data.

> The following LateError was thrown building UserProfile(dirty, state: _UserProfileState#752a9):
> LateInitializationError: Field '_userData@32329253' has not been initialized."

Here's the code:

```
    late final User _user;
    late final DocumentSnapshot _userData;
    
      @override
      void initState() {  
        super.initState();
        _initUser();
      }
    
      void _initUser() async {
        _user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
        try {
          _userData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .doc(_user.uid)
              .get();
        } catch (e) {
          print("something went wrong");
        }
      }
```

The build function is not even running as i tried to print _user and _userData to check if they have been initialized.
If i try to print _user and _userData in initUser() function, _user gets printed and _userData gets printed after the error statements. 
Please help me find a way out through this error.

Comment: Have you checked your logs?! Firebase always tells you the error. Don't use try catch.

Comment: BTW you're using a lateinit on the wrong scope. Remove your lateinit keyword for _userData

Comment: first i was not using try catch still got the same error and removing late keyword does not compile as it's obvious that final variables needs to be initialized

Comment: you need to use optionals if you're not going to use a lateinit

Comment: you're trying to use a "final" variable from a future method on a override method that is not happening over the object construction. Lateinit exists for specific cases but it doesn't work for the logic you're trying to use.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even though you are initializing these variables inside the `initUser()`, but you will get this error if you are using the variables inside the `build()` method since `initUser()` is asynchronous meaning it will take time to get the data from the collection. To solve this you can do:

```
@override
      void initState() {  
        super.initState();
        _initUser().whenComplete((){
          setState(() {});
       });
      }
```

This will rebuild the widget tree with the new values.

Comment: Can this be used with the snippet in the OP? Because I get an error saying 'This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used'.

Answer (score 20):

In my case, I faced this error while using `easy_localization`. I forgot:

```
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
```

on main.dart file.

P.S. I know this is not the answer to this question, I wrote this for someone who faced this issue like my case.

Answer (score -12):

I have resolved this by simply running below command:

```
dart migrate --skip-import-check--ignore-exceptions
```

Comment: Skipping errors is different from resolving them