# flutter: LateInitializationError: Field 'name' has not been initialized

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Error: Runner[463:34314] flutter: LateInitializationError: Field 'name' has not been initialized.

I recently updated to using firebase core and nullsafety and made some changes to my code that I don't quite understand, I'm new to programming here. Any way, I've tried reading this similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66734015/lateinitializationerror-field-userdata32329253-has-not-been-initialized) about it but I still don't quite grasp it. I understand that I am not using name properly in the initstate most likely but that is as much as I understand. Can someone please provide an example code of what's needed to solve for the error below?

2021-04-10 17:59:41.331476-0700 Runner[463:34314] flutter: LateInitializationError: Field 'name' has not been initialized.

```
class MyService extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyServiceState createState() => _MyServiceState();
}

class _MyServiceState extends State<MyService> {
  late String name, email;
  Widget currentWidget = BackgroundBetcher();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    findNameAnEmail();
  }

  Future<Null> findNameAnEmail() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp().then((value) async {
      FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((event) {
        setState(() {
          name = event!.displayName!;
          email = event.email!;
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: MyStyle().primaryColor,
      ),
      drawer: buildDrawer(),
      body: currentWidget,
    );
  }

  Drawer buildDrawer() {
    return Drawer(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              buildUserAccountsDrawerHeader(),
              buildListTileShowCartoonList(),
              buildListTileInformation(),
            ],
          ),
          buildSignOut(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  ListTile buildListTileShowCartoonList() {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(
        Icons.face,
        size: 36,
      ),
      title: Text('Manual Location Update'),
      subtitle: Text('Send a single location update'),
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          currentWidget = PageWidget();
        });
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );
  }

  ListTile buildListTileInformation() {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(
        Icons.perm_device_info,
        size: 36,
      ),
      title: Text('Background Location Fetch Log'),
      subtitle: Text('History of recorded locations'),
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          currentWidget = BackgroundBetcher();
        });
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );
  }

  UserAccountsDrawerHeader buildUserAccountsDrawerHeader() {
    return UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('images/wall.jpg'), fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ),
      accountName: MyStyle().titleH3(name),
      accountEmail: MyStyle().titleH3(email),
      currentAccountPicture: Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
    );
  }

  Column buildSignOut() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        ListTile(
          onTap: () async {
            await Firebase.initializeApp().then((value) async {
              await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut().then((value) =>
                  Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                      context, '/authen', (route) => false));
            });
          },
          tileColor: MyStyle().darkColor,
          leading: Icon(
            Icons.exit_to_app,
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 36,
          ),
          title: MyStyle().titleH2White('Sign Out'),
          subtitle: MyStyle().titleH3White('Sign Out & Go to Authen'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I've answered your question, but on another note: `Future<void>` is preferred over `Future<Null>` since the release of Dart 2.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You should be checking for nullable for the variable `name`. So, Use:

`String? name;`

instead of:

`late String name`

Late means,

> I promise I will initialize this variable later

but this promise doesn't mean a thing when using that variable inside the build method.

Comment: Android Studio suggests using late when updating to null safety, it took me awhile to figure out that the '?' was what was needed, thanks for this.

Comment: Not gonna lie, null safety has been a pain

Comment: I am not sure how replacing late initialized variable with a nullable one solves the issue? This is mostly a problem with the subject calling something in the wrong order and the Flutter compiler is smart enough to figure that out.

Answer (score 6):

`findNameAnEmail` is an asynchronous method, so, while it's called in `initState`, Flutter does not wait for it to complete before `build` is called. This results in your late fields being accessed before they are set.

In order to wait for a `Future` to complete before building, consider using [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

Comment: Thanks for reading and answering, I now understand the purpose of FutureBuilder but not how to implement. Could you please provide an example of the changes I need to make? Thank you.

Comment: I would consider this as the correct answer. Upvoted!

Answer (score 3):

For **LateInitializationError**, Simply use **`int? count;`** instead of **`late int count;`**

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem of lateInitializationError I find out to use `?` to avoid it. if some one is facing this problem instead of `late` try `?`.

For Example:

```
Gender? selectedGender;
```

Answer (score 1):

As i was facing the same problem i used the Future Builder the snapshot.data cant be null to handle this just use if block (snapshot.data==null) then return container with child cneter Text('Loading') until future completes screen will show loading and then will display data[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHomD.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a static make sure that it is not already initialized (singleton pattern with nullable variable) or removed the "static" keyword.

Switching from

```
static late final ScrollController scrollController;
```

to

```
 late final ScrollController scrollController;
```

got rid of my error.

Answer (score -1):

I'm very new to flutter, but this worked for me.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    findNameAndEmail().whenComplete(() {
        setState(() {});
    });
}
```

Comment: Not working for me Still getting error `LateInitializationError: Field '_cartFuture@52302676' has not been initialized.`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this method for a couple of reasons.

First of all, it's not safe. There's no guarantee that the widget will still be mounted when `setState` is called, and if it's not, a runtime error will occur.

Additionally, it's not optimised. Rather than rebuilding the entire widget, using something like `FutureBuilder` will only rebuilt the components that use the future.